# double linked lists and filling

Tags: c#, data-structures

I am working on a Data Structures project and have made a telephone directory. It is a windows form app. There are 2 parts of it; one is the home directory and other is the organization directory.

The home directory uses queues to take first and last name and number of the contact and saves it to a .txt file.

The organization directory uses double linked list to perform same operation and save organization name and number to a new node and then to a .txt file.

Now the problem is that though it saves to the .txt file (linked list) i am unable to search and delete that element from file as well as the linked list. I have tried everything and searched tons of websites but to no use...please help i just have two days to submit my project ;(
this is my code to insert data to doubly linked list and save to file behind the insert buttone

```
   linked_list l;

    string data;
    bool check = true;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

                int id = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                string name = textBox2.Text;
                string phone = textBox3.Text;
                try
                {
                    data = "";
                    if (check)
                    {
                        if (comboBox1.Text == "First")
                        {
                            l.InsertFirst(id, name, phone);
                            data = label1.Text + ":" + textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + label2.Text + ":" + textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + label3.Text + ":" + textBox3.Text + Environment.NewLine+Environment.NewLine;
                            File.AppendAllText("Organization Directory.txt", data);
                            MessageBox.Show("DATA SAVED");
                        }
                        else if (comboBox1.Text == "Last")
                        {
                            l.InsertLast(id, name, phone);
                            data = label1.Text + ":" + textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + label2.Text + ":" + textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + label3.Text + ":" + textBox3.Text + Environment.NewLine+Environment.NewLine;
                            File.AppendAllText("Organization Directory.txt", data);
                            MessageBox.Show("DATA SAVED");
                        }
                    } display();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Source);
                }

    }
    public void display()
    {

                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                Nodes n = l.head;
                while (n != null)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(label1.Text + ":" + n.id).ToString();
                    listBox1.Items.Add(n.name).ToString();
                    listBox1.Items.Add(label3.Text + ":" + n.phone).ToString();
                    listBox1.Items.Add(Environment.NewLine).ToString();
                    n = n.next;
                }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by unable?  Do you mean you don't know how, or you've tried something and it didn't work?  If you post some code, you'll get a much better response.

Comment: Hard to point you in a direction with this (little) much information, but I suspect that the choice of txt file for your linked list means you are talking about about rewriting the entire file, or some sort of soft delete.

Comment: no i have tried many ways i have developed the complete application on windows forms c# but now i am stuck with this problem that how do i file my linked list contacts to notepad...i have tried a way and it does add my contact name and number to notepad but doesnt retireve r search r delete from notepad through application

Comment: Search, retrieve, delete... sounds like you want a database, not a text file. The data storage mechanism (database, textfile) is totally separate from the data structure you use to represent the data in your application.

Comment: but we are not allowed to use the database in our project i have done it with the queues it saves name and number in a queue and writes it to the notepad then searches as well as deletes...there must be a way for the linked lists too..can anyone plz help